# If $f_A(x)=(x+3)^2(x-1)^2$ and $m_A(x) \ne f_A(x)$ then $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that the following statement shouldn't be true :

> Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix which satisfies $f_A(x)=(x+3)^2(x-1)^2$ and $m_A(x) \ne f_A(x)$ then $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$.

Notice that $f_A(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and $m_A(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$.

I'm trying to look for a counter-example but I can't find any. I tried to pick some diagonal matrices but I found out it cannot be an appropriate counter-example because a diagonal matrix is always diagonalizable. Besides that, all I tried is some other guessing where the diagonal contains $-3,-3,1,1$ with different combinations of $1$'s on the upper diagonal and the lower diagonal.

Is there any way to construct such a matrix?

$\underline {\mbox {Note:}}$

I know that the opposite statement is correct (that is, if we knew that $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$ then $m_A(x) \ne f_A(x)$ because $m_A(x)$ must be simple in that case and we know $f_A(x)$ is not simple).

Comment: What's $f_A$?${}$

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the minimal polynomial being "simple": what it **must** be for the matrix to be diagonalizable is the product of **different** linear factores, and thus in your question's case this leads to the min. pol. to be different from the one given. BTW, is $\;f_A\;$ the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane The characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Comment: @Timbuc Yes, It is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a counterexample:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}-3&0&0&0\\0&-3&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I probably did some of my calculations wrong. I'll try to find our what is $m_A(x)$ for this matrix again. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure $f_A(x) \ne m_A(x)$?

Comment: Yes @SyndicatorBBB. Did you try it already?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying again. Just a second.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I tried to set $m_A(x)=(x+3)^2(x-1)$ and see if $m_A(A)=0$. It wasn't, then I tried to set $m_A(x)=(x+3)(x-1)^2$ and see if $m_A(A)=0$. Yet it's not. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: $$(A+3I)(A-I)^2= \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&4&1\\0&0&0&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}16&0&0&0\\0&16&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ so yes: you probably made some arithmetic mistake.

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB The point here is that $\;f_A(x)\neq m_A(x)\;$ *in this particular case* **doesn't force** $\;m_A(x)=(x+3)(x-1)\;$ , i.e., the min. pol. doesn't *have* to be the product of different linear factors, and thus the matrix doesn't have to be diagonalizable

Comment: Timbuc I appreciate your help so much and I'm sorry for driving you crazy only because of arithmetic mistake. Thank you so much for the kind help. I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB Anytime. This stuff is cool but it is pretty hard work with the arithmetic, and mistakes flourish here.